# Deploying multiple container with same code (Docker)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a custom build image (Python + project) which is working fine, I just want to deploy multiple container using docker-compose only environment variables will be changing rest is same can it be done from one service in docker-compose.yml

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  logsService:
    image: logs:latest # logs image is already built and working fine
    env_file:
      - /home/controller/test/.env # File contains url, api_key, api_secret
```

by using docker-compose up I can provision one container but I want to provision 4 container with same code but different env variables (i.e. url, api_key, api_secret), any ideas how to achieve this will be appriciated

NOTE: I am new to docker, please pardon me if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, something like this perhaps:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  logsService:
    image: logs:latest
    env_file:
      - /home/controller/test/${ENV:-}.env
```

`ENV=prod docker-compose --project-name prod up`

assuming that your production config is in "prod.env"

Comment: Thank your for your help I will try this as well

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with the docker-compose command

```
docker-compose --scale --name="numberofcontainers"
```

so for if I wanted to launch my "webserver" container 3 times it would be

```
docker-compse --scale --webserver=3
```

as you have said you are new I would advise looking into a load balancer aswell. Or your other containers will be usless

Comment: thanks for your support, can the env_file be changed some how so that i have 3 container with same code and different env variables.

Comment: you would need to define the different env_files somewhere, how ever the short answer is not easy. it would be better to have 3 different .yaml files for your env. This will also make it easier to keep track of things

Comment: Okay, noted I will try that.